# Good-looking way to conditionally add attribute to EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got many `@Html.EditorFor` object like this in my cshtml file:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => product.size_L, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control size_L calculateOffer acceptIntegerOnly", @tabIndex = "1", @autocomplete = "off" } })
```

I need to add `@readonly = "readonly"` attribute to some of EditorFor objects, but only for some of them and only when `product.enableReadonly == true`.

Of course I can do it similar to this:

```
@if (product.enableReadonly)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => product.size_L, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control size_L calculateOffer acceptIntegerOnly", @tabIndex = "1", @autocomplete = "off" } })
}
else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => product.size_L, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control size_L calculateOffer acceptIntegerOnly", @tabIndex = "1", @autocomplete = "off", @readonly="readonly" } })
}
```

but it definitely doesn't look good. And what about situation when I have more those "optional" attributes to add? The code would expand even more.

So, can you think of some smart, compact solution?

Comment: I pretty much do like your question, but I would like to suggest you that you [edit] it reword those "good-looking" phrases to something else that is more concrete, just because it currently is kinda opinionated.

Comment: I don't like this phrase too. I deleted it from question details, but I can't think of anything better for title. In fact question is subjective just because I need subjective answer ;) I solved it in question details, but I'm looking for better way

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but isn't your conditional statement wrong with the result that you are looking for?  You only want the readonly attribute to be set if `product.enableReadonly == true`.. so `if (product.enableReadonly) //means true`.. then the first `EditorFor` should have the attribute of readonly, right?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory, but in order to clean my huge `EditorFor` calls, I created some overloaded methods like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TItem>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr, bool readOnly)
{
            if (readOnly)
            {
                return html.EditorFor(expr, new
                {
                    htmlAttributes = new
                    {
                        @class = "form-control size_L calculateOffer acceptIntegerOnly",
                        tabIndex = "1",
                        autocomplete = "off",
                        @readonly = "readonly"
                    }
                });
            }

            return html.EditorFor(expr, new
            {
                htmlAttributes = new
                {
                    @class = "form-control size_L calculateOffer acceptIntegerOnly",
                    tabIndex = "1",
                    autocomplete = "off"
                }
            });
 }
```